# Django: Insert json data in django request.Post

Tags: python, html, json, django, request

I want to put my json object in django request

here its my html code

```
<form method="post" action="/IE/changePassword/" >
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><h4>Mobile Number : </h4></td>
      <td><input name="userName"  type="text" class="meta" style=" font-size: 0.9em; width:300px; height: 25px;"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><h4>Old Password : </h4></td>
      <td><input name="oldPassword" type="password" class="meta" style=" font-size: 0.9em; width:300px; height : 25px;"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><h4>New Password : </h4></td>
      <td><input name="newPassword1" type="password" class="meta" style=" font-size: 0.9em; width:300px; height : 25px;"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><h4>Retype Password : </h4></td>
      <td><input name="newPassword2" size="60" type="password" class="meta" style=" font-size: 0.9em; width:300px; height : 25px;"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><input  type="submit" name="Change Password" value="Change Password" style="width:250px; height : 40px; margin-left:100px; background-color: #00B16A; font-size: 1.4em; color:#ffffff;"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

here it's my django code

```
   newPassword1 = request.POST['newPassword1']
    newPassword2 = request.POST['newPassword2']
    oldPassword = request.POST['oldPassword']
    userName = request.POST['userName']
    IERequest = "ieRequest"
    changePassObj = {"IERequestChangePass": IERequest, "newPassword1": newPassword1, "newPassword2": newPassword2, "oldPassword": oldPassword, "userName": userName}
    request._POST = json.dumps(changePassObj)
```

I want to put above changePassObj in request

output of above code

```
<WSGIRequest
path:/IE/changePassword/,
GET:<QueryDict: {}>,
POST:<QueryDict: {u'userName': [u'1234567890'], u'oldPassword': [u'xcz'], u'Change Password': [u'Change Password'], u'newPassword2': [u'abc'], u'newPassword1': [u'abc']}>,
```

expected output

```
POST:<QueryDict: {u'userName': [u'1234567890'], u'oldPassword': [u'xcz'], u'Change Password': [u'Change Password'], u'newPassword2': [u'abc'], u'newPassword1': [u'abc']}, u''IERequestChangePass': [u'ieRequest]>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use hidden inputs in the form to pass the data back. (http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms07.htm)